C++/WinRT RequestAsync memory leak
I'm trying to figure out the cause of a memory leak in the following program. Running it causes memory usage to increase from 2MB -> 5MB (as reported by Visual Studio diagnostic tools) in about 10000 loops.
#include "pch.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <roapi.h>
#include <windows.media.control.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "runtimeobject.lib")

#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>

using namespace ABI::Windows::Media::Control;

int main()
{
    winrt::init_apartment();

    IGlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManagerStatics* ok;
    winrt::hstring hs{ L"Windows.Media.Control.GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager" };
    HRESULT hr = RoGetActivationFactory(reinterpret_cast<HSTRING>(get_abi(hs)), IID_IGlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManagerStatics, (void**)&ok);
    int c = 0;
    wchar_t text_buffer[20] = { 0 };
    AsyncStatus status;
    IGlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager* sm;

    while (true)
    {
        c++;
        __FIAsyncOperation_1_Windows__CMedia__CControl__CGlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager* ok2;
        ok->RequestAsync(&ok2);
        IAsyncInfo* ok3;
        ok2->QueryInterface(&ok3);
        while (true) {
            ok3->get_Status(&status);
            if (status != AsyncStatus::Started) {
                if (status != AsyncStatus::Completed) {
                    return 0;
                }
                break;
            }
            //Sleep(1);
        }
        ok2->GetResults(&sm);
        sm->Release();
        sm = nullptr;
        ok3->Close();
        ok3->Release();
        ok2->Release();
        ok3 = nullptr;
        ok2 = nullptr;

        if (c % 1000 == 0) {
            swprintf(text_buffer, _countof(text_buffer), L"%d\n", c); // convert
            OutputDebugString(text_buffer); // print
            Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

Omitting the waiting for the result of the RequestAsync call and replacing it with ok3->Cancel(); pretty much fixes the leak, memory usage plateaus at around 4MB: I guess I'm handling IAsyncInfo wrong somehow?
I've also let the program run for a longer period of time, and the memory usage doesn't decrease (eg the garbage collector isn't kicking in with a delay or something like that).
The actual application I'm developing is written in AutoHotkey and uses Windows.Media.Ocr, where a leak of same proportions occurs and resolves if I cancel the RequestAsync call. Looping 1000s of times is realistic in that scenario, and leads to significant memory increases.
This is also the reason why my example code doesn't use smart pointers etc.
Edit: a simpler variation that also leaks:
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Media.Control.h>

winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction MyAc() {
    using namespace winrt::Windows::Media::Control;
    while (true)
    {
        auto manager = co_await GlobalSystemMediaTransportControlsSessionManager::RequestAsync();
    }
}

int main()
{
    winrt::init_apartment();
    MyAction().get();
    return 0;
}

